# Find reflection vector of 2 lines in 2D with General form

Tags: geometry, programming, reflection

I am having problems computing the reflection of 2 lines using the General form `(Ax + By + C = 0)`. I am currently using the following method:
We have lines a and b;
`vector_x = dot_product(a.colinear().normalize(), b.colinear().normalize());`
`vector_y = sqrt(1-vector_x^2);`

In words that would look like:
`vector_x` is equal to the dot product of the normalized colinear vectors of both lines
`vector_y` is equal to the square root of `1 - vector_x ^ 2`

This outputs a vector that needs to be rotated `180 - angleToXAxis*2` degrees

In the following picture the green line acts as a mirror for the blue line which needs to be reflected. The output is the vector near the `(0,0)` point (I can't post images so you would have to use the link):
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsDPd.png)

I am currently struggling to rotate the vector so I would appreciate if someone can provide a formula for it. Also if someone knows a better way of doing it suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: Is this a mathematics question or a programming question?

Comment: Both, I don't mind.

Comment: Blue and red are reflections of each other...

Comment: Green line acts as a mirror for blue line, red line is the produced reflection

Comment: What is the vector that you are talking about?

Comment: The produced vector starts at (0,0) and goes to ~(0.7, 0.7)

Comment: But the lines do not make $45$ degrees with the $x$-axis! https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=arctan%285%2F4%29